# python3 odd filepath question; no bugs in code per se; purely for knowledge

Tags: python-3.x, directory, system, filepath, subdirectory

1. I have a script that uses the os.system module to run an .exe;

   ```
   system('program.exe -ARG') #notice no r'file/type/path.exe'
   ```
2. I keep this script in a sub-folder (Folder B)
3. but for whatever reason it cannot find program.exe when it's in Folder B, but
4. it does find the .exe and works perfectly fine in the main folder (Folder A) where I keep the main module, but
5. even when I am not running the main module in Folder A and testing the script in folder B, same thing, it only detects program.exe in Folder A
6. It should be noted that I initially created the file for the script in folder A and then moved it to Folder B then wrote the code to run the executable

What is happening?

Comment: Check the _actual_ working directory with `os.getcwd()`.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. But why does it like Folder A instead of Folder B in all cases? What determines the Current Working Directory?